# Why do multiple-table joins produce duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have three tables A, B, and C. Each has two columns: a primary key and some other piece of data. They each have the same number of rows. If I `JOIN` A and B on the primary key, I should end up with the same number of rows as are in either of them (as opposed to A.rows * B.rows).

Now, if I `JOIN` `A JOIN B` with `C`, why do I end up with duplicate rows? I have run into this problem on several occasions and I do not understand it. It seems like it should produce the same result as `JOIN`ing `A` and `B` since it has the same number of rows but, instead, duplicates are produced.

Queries that produce results like this are of the format

```
SELECT *
FROM M
    INNER JOIN S
        on M.mIndex = S.mIndex
    INNER JOIN D
        ON M.platformId LIKE '%' + D.version + '%'
    INNER JOIN H
        ON D.Name = H.Name
        AND D.revision = H.revision
```

Here are schemas for the tables. H contains is a historic table containing everything that was ever in D. There are many M rows for each D and one S for each M.

Table M

```
    [mIndex] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [platformId] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ip] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [complete] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeployId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES D.DeployId,
    [source] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Table S

```
[order] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[parameters] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
[Finished] [bit] NOT NULL,
[mIndex] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[mDeployId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Date] [datetime] NULL,
[status] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[output] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[config] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Table D

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[branch] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[revision] [int] NOT NULL,
[version] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[path] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
```

Table H

```
[IdDeploy] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[version] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
[path] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Revision] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
```

I didn't post the tables and query initially because I am more interested in understanding this problem for myself and avoiding it in the future.

Comment: What is the full query you are running?

Comment: It depends very much on the kind of joins you are using.

Comment: You may be making a Cartesian join. The wiki page has examples of this and other types of joins - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: @mikeyq6 I added an example

Comment: @sirdank That's not a useful example without an additional sample of the data you're querying.

Comment: @JosephB I don't believe that's the case. Please see my revised question.

Comment: @MattThrower Please forgive me, I do not understand. What can I do (aside from posting the contents of my database, which I cannot) to help you?

Comment: @sirdank You post a small selection of the data. Or, at the very least, the table definitions. But to be honest your question is really about the mechanics of how joins work rather than a specific problem.

Comment: @MattThrower That is on purpose. I am intentionally asking about the mechanics of joins in order to understand them better. I want to learn to fish instead of ask SO for a fish whenever I get hungry. I'll post the table definitions and update the sample query.

Comment: This is a strange example. You want all tables's keys to match? Provided they really are the tables' IDs as their names suggest, they would be unique and you couldn't posiibly get any duplicates. I think you have given a wrong example.

Comment: If one of the tables M, S, D, or H has more than one row for a given Id (if just the Id column is not the PK), then the query would result in "duplicate" rows. If you have more than one row for an Id in a table, then the other columns, which would uniquely identify a row, also must be included in the JOIN condition(s).

Comment: @JosephB You may have solved my problem. I think the answer is that I need to use all keys in the join condition. I didn't realize that was necessary or that I wasn't doing it. It makes sense though. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @sirdank Yes, please use all the key columns in your join condition to avoid "duplicate" rows. I have included my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If one of the tables `M`, `S`, `D`, or `H` has more than one row for a given `Id` (if just the `Id` column is not the Primary Key), then the query would result in "duplicate" rows. If you have more than one row for an `Id` in a table, then the other columns, which would uniquely identify a row, also must be included in the JOIN condition(s).

**References**:

[Related Question on MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48bb4a3b-5c71-4e33-913b-7f577754f870/when-join-two-tables-with-composite-primary-keys-what-will-be-best-performance-use-some-fields-or?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 82):

When you have related tables you often have one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. So when you join to TableB each record in TableA many have multiple records in TableB.  This is normal and expected.

Now at times you only need certain columns and those are all the same for all the records, then you would need to do some sort of group by or distinct to remove the duplicates. Let's look at an example:

```
TableA
Id Field1
1  test
2  another test

TableB
ID Field2 field3
1  Test1  something
1  test1  More something
2  Test2  Anything
```

So when you join them and select all the files you get:

```
select * 
from tableA a 
join tableb b on a.id = b.id

a.Id a.Field1        b.id   b.field2  b.field3
1    test            1      Test1     something
1    test            1      Test1     More something
2    another test 2  2      Test2     Anything
```

These are not duplicates because the values of Field3 are different even though there are repeated values in the earlier fields. Now when you only select certain columns the same number of records are being joined together but since the columns with the different information is not being displayed they look like duplicates.

```
select a.Id, a.Field1,  b.field2
from tableA a 
join tableb b on a.id = b.id

a.Id a.Field1       b.field2  
1    test           Test1     
1    test           Test1 
2    another test   Test2
```

This appears to be duplicates but it is not because of the multiple records in TableB.

You normally fix this by using aggregates and group by, by using distinct or by filtering in the where clause to remove duplicates. How you solve this depends on exactly what your business rule is and how your database is designed and what kind of data is in there.

Comment: I was missing a "Group By" argument & this helped me. Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 1):

Ok in this example you are getting duplicates because you are joining both D and S onto M.
I assume you should be joining D.id onto S.id like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM M
INNER JOIN S
    on M.Id = S.Id
INNER JOIN D
    ON S.Id = D.Id
INNER JOIN H
    ON D.Id = H.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like a really basic "DUH" answer, but make sure that the column you're using to Lookup from on the merging file is actually full of unique values!

I noticed earlier today that PowerQuery won't throw you an error (like in PowerPivot) and will happily allow you to run a Many-Many merge.  This will result in multiple rows being produced for each record that matches with a non-unique value.

Answer (score 1):

> **Make sure your join query is correct: i was facing this issue due to**
> **join query issue**

```
   /****** Script for command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT  [TransWorkShopNo]
      ,[TransformerCapacity].[CapacistyPrice]
      ,[TransformerCapacity].[HTCoilPrice]
      ,[TransformerCapacity].[LTCoilReclaimedPrice]
      ,[TransformerCapacity].[LTCoilNewPrice]

  FROM [Hi-Lit-Electronics].[dbo].[TransformerData] inner join  TransformerCapacity on [TransformerData].CapacistyID= [TransformerCapacity].CapacistyID 
   inner join  TransformerItem on [TransformerData].ItemID= TransformerCapacity.ItemID
```

> **TransformerCapacity.ItemID**
> Here this was wrong

Answer (score 0):

use group by clause on main table id i hope it works
$this->db->**group_by**('products.id'); for **codeigniter**