# Fixing Error in Django Rest Framework Model Serializer Related Primary Key Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I feel like I'm chasing my tail here and so I've come to your fine folks to help me understand where I've screwed up and why my thinking on this must be flawed in some way.

I'm writing an API in DRF and while it doesn't have a lot of tables in the DB, there are many to many relationships in the DB which makes it feel complicated, or at least it makes it difficult to just view the db tables and intuitively understand what's related.

First my model. I'm getting this when attempting to POST a new object to the `jobs` model. I'm needing to validate that the requesting worker has the permission to create a `job` with the related `target` and `workergroup`

#### Models:

```
class Workers(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    workerid = models.CharField(max_length=16, verbose_name="Worker ID", unique=True, default="Empty")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default=1)
    workername = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="Worker Friendly Name", default="")
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    awsarn = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name="ARN Name of Worker", blank=True, null=True)
    customerrights = models.ManyToManyField(Customers, related_name="access_rights", default="")


class Targets(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name="Target Friendly Name", unique=False)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=120, verbose_name="Target Hostname", default="")
    ipaddr = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='both', unpack_ipv4=True, default="", null=True)


class WorkerGroups(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Default Group")
    workers = models.ManyToManyField(Workers)


class Jobs(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey(Targets, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
    enddate = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    frequency = models.TimeField(default='00:05')
    workergroup = models.ForeignKey(WorkerGroups, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    jobdefinition = models.ForeignKey(JobDefinitions, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

In my serializers I have a `JobSerializer` which is referencing PrimaryKeyRelatedField classes which I *think* should have the effect of limiting the queryset which validates those related models. BTW, the `customerrightsids` are being built in the view and that seems to work fine for all other models.

#### Serializers:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        print("In Custom TargetPK get_queryset")
        queryset = Targets.objects.filter(customer_id__in=self.context['auth'].customerrightsids)
        if isinstance(queryset, (QuerySet, Manager)):
            queryset = queryset.all()
        return queryset


class WorkerGroupPKSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        print("In Custom WorkerGroupPK get_queryset")
        queryset = WorkerGroups.objects.filter(workers__customer_id__in=self.context['auth'].customerrightsids)
        if isinstance(queryset, (QuerySet, Manager)):
            queryset = queryset.all()
        return queryset

class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    workergroup = WorkerGroupPKSerializer(many=False) # Commenting this out removes error
    target = TargetPKSerializer(many=False) # This seems to work fine even though it's similar to the line above

    class Meta:
        model = Jobs
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(self.context['auth'])
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

There's nothing special in the create method of the viewset object. It's taking the request and passing a couple into the ViewSet and updating its context. I can share that if needed, but that doesn't seem to be where the issue is.

So finally, for the error. When I perform a `POST` to `/jobs/` I'm getting the following:

#### Error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /jobs/
get() returned more than one WorkerGroups -- it returned 2!
```

The error clearly states that I'm getting multiple WorkerGroups returned in a get() but I don't know where or how to resolve that in this case.

It is clearly a problem with the WorkerGroupPKSerializer. If I comment out the reference to it from the JobSerializer the error goes away. That stops the validation of that field though, so that's not a workable solution!

Comment: Sorry for the junk title, I didn't know what else to call it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm on the right track here, but it seems you might have a problem of duplicate/multiple results. You should try and use `.distinct()` on the `Queryset` in `WorkerGroupPKSerializer` (also, see [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) docs). You used a `ForeignKey` on the `customer` property of the `Worker` model, so that makes it possible to have multiple `Worker`'s belonging to the same `WorkerGroup` matching the filter query, thus returning the same `WorkerGroup` twice. So when the `id` of that `WorkerGroup` is `POST`ed, the `get()` will match two results, throwing that error.

Commenting out seems to clear the error, and this would be because of the fact that you're also commenting out `many=False`, thus, `.get()` is not called anymore. But as mentioned in the question, this would disable the custom queryset used to filter on.

Comment: Thank you my kind Sasja! I think I'm following you but I'll have to sort it in the morning when I've had a better night's rest. This looks like the best lead I've had all day!

Comment: Ok! That totally worked. I'm reading over your comment again. I understand conceptually how uniqueness eliminates duplicates. But I'm not sure if I understand the specific duplication that is happening here. Workers are "owned" buy a specific customer but many workers can be members of many workergroups. I understand the duplication due to the workergroup, but not necessarily due to the customer. I'm going to post my updated serializer in an answer below, just for the sake of posterity.

Comment: @JarredMasterson the underlying cause comes from how RDBMS like MySQL work (found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786401/why-do-multiple-table-joins-produce-duplicate-rows) question on SO)

Basically, you filtered on customer's id's in `Worker`s (django orm doing multiple sql `JOIN`s underlying to 'get to' that table), so every time a customer's id is encountered it says 'filter = true' so return `WorkerGroup`. So if it encounters a customer id twice, it will return a WorkerGroup each time (possibly the same).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sasja's answer. Here is the updated WorkerGroupPKSerializer that now works.

```
class WorkerGroupPKSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def get_queryset(self):
        print("In Custom WorkerGroupPK get_queryset")
        queryset = WorkerGroups.objects.filter(workers__customer_id__in=self.context['auth'].customerrightsids).distinct()
        if isinstance(queryset, (QuerySet, Manager)):
            queryset = queryset.all()
        return queryset
```