# How to add same dataset in Quicksight to join with multiple datasets while creating joined dataset?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I have few datasets which are created in aws quicksight from s3 containing json data. I have a requirement to join for ex alpha dataset with beta and gamma without duplicating the fields. Is there any way I can achieve this?

If not is there an alternative to achieve this maybe using Athena?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way database joins work: If multiple rows satisfy the join condition due to there being a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship between the table, then rows are duplicated. See [Why do multiple-table joins produce duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786401/why-do-multiple-table-joins-produce-duplicate-rows)

In the context of QuickSight see https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/duplicated-data-in-qs-left-join/1393 for a possible workaround for this.