# Three total tables, count number of records from tables 1 and 2 that are connected to table 3

Tags: sql

I have three tables, Tb_Requests, TB_Offers, and Tb_Product.

TB_Offers:
Prod_ID

Tb_Requests:
Prod_ID

Tb_Product:
Prod_ID
Name

I need to list the Name from Tb_Product with the count from Tb_Requests and TB_Offers that match Tb_Product in one query.

This is what I have so far:

select p.[Name], count(o.Supp_ID) '# of Offers', count(r.Con_ID) '# of Requests'
from Tb_Requests r, TB_Offers o, Tb_Product p
where r.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID and o.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
group by p.[Name]

Results:
Name    |  # of Offers |    # of Requests

- Airplane |6  |6
- Auto   |      25 |25
- Computer |72 |72
- Milk  |       16 |16
- Oil  |        20 |20
- Orange   |        36 |36
- Truck    |        6  |6
- TV    |       20 |20

but my results should be:
NAME          |                 # of Offers | # of Requests

---

- Airplane        |               6    |       1
- Auto           |                5     |      5
- Computer        |               12    |      6
- Milk            |               4     |      4
- Oil              |              4     |      5
- Orange          |               6     |      6
- Truck            |              6      |     1
- TV              |               4     |      5

(8 row(s) affected)

I need to combine these two queries:
select p.[Name], count(o.Supp_ID) '# of Offers'
from TB_Offers o, Tb_Product p 
where p.Prod_ID = o.Prod_ID
group by p.[Name]

select p.[Name], count(r.Con_ID) '# of Requests'
from Tb_Requests r, Tb_Product p  
where p.Prod_ID = r.Prod_ID
group by p.[Name]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you are seeing is because of the number of rows in each table - for "Oil" there are 4 rows in Offers and 5 and Requests, giving you 20 rows total.

There are a few options here. You can re-write your query to use outer apply to each of the Offers and Requests tables, giving you a distinct aggregate figure for each to join to. You don't specify your RDMS, but you likely can also try `count(distinct )` to give you a distinct count as well.

There are some good resources to read more about this - try: [Why do multiple-table joins produce duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786401/why-do-multiple-table-joins-produce-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Thank you BishNaboB! All I needed was the distinct. What threw me off was that both counts came back with the same numbers. I truly appreciate your assistance!